# Access to Watchkit Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit, watchos, watchos-3

I'm trying to save data into Watchkit Extension CoreData, but I don't get the way to do this.

In iOs case, you do this:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate!).persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data")
context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

The main problem is that I'm not able to get the context in Watchkit Extension to fetch the request.

Any idea? Thanks any case!

Comment: I'm also recently searching for the best way to do this with watchOS 4. To connect to you iOS app you can use the `WatchConnectivity` framework, but I have problems doing fetch requests there. Did you find any solution to this?